# Selenium couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website, I need to login to it to continue and when I try to do so I get this error:

```
[5064:9952:0514/222545.212:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate
```

Here is my code:

```python
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

capabilities = {
    'acceptInsecureCerts': True
}

# Set up driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get(login_url)

# Locate user login form fields
username_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-email-input')
password_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-password-input')

# Fill in the fields
username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)

# Click the submit button
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-submit-button')
submit_button.click()
```

My browser is up to date.
I tried adding arguments to options like:
`options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')`,
`options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`
and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I did not wait for something to load. Anyways here is the working code:

```
# Set up driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(login_url)

# Login to the site
username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-email-input')1)
username_input.send_keys(username)

password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-password-input'))
password_input.send_keys(password)

login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tst-login-submit-button'))
login.click()
```